# Injecting headless chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

I am wanting to use headless Chrome but with extensions.  I realise this is not possible.  I realise there are lots of good GitHub projects which make use of javascript and behave like extensions.

My question is, and I know there are easily ways of doing this with addons but headless chrome makes this impossible.

How do I go about injecting default firefox/Chrome with javascript without addons so I am able to use headless Chrome/Firefox as well as GitHub projects

Comment: Unrelated to Selenium.  You'd have to inject default Firefox developer this way.  I'd love for a privacy Firefox to be built without extensions.  Or even one where adblocker is in the default build as to keep cpu at a minimum.  As extensions are not going to be supported this sounds interesting...

Comment: This project may be of use: https://www.fullstackpython.com/javascript.html - Bottom line, no easy way to do this.

Comment: What requirements do you have for extensions? If you're looking to test extensions, you're out of luck for headless browsers. Have you considered using xvfb instead of headless modes?

Comment: @sytech I have never used Linux before.  Is it cpu intensive xvfb or nearly as good as chrome headless.  I might have to use linux

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to run headless? Also what's the reason you need extensions? Typically, the requirement for headless is to test on servers that are headless. For instance, I use xvfb for automated testing of headed browsers with Travis-CI. xvfb itself has not affected the speed of my tests, other than the 3 seconds it needs to start up. However, since the browsers run in a normal headed mode, they take more resources than if they were to run headless. In my case, there is still no resource bottleneck, so no issue there. But if you have a screen already, why headless?

Comment: @sytech I use windows and I want to reduce cpu.  But I also want to reduce fingerprinting